# Auto-resizing Spark TextArea using Flex Hero

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to auto-resize a Spark TextArea using Flex Hero but having no luck. Can anyone point me in the direction of a working example please?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to auto-resize the TextArea when typing, so there's never a scroll bar.

Comment: Do you want autoresize when you typing, like when adding more text area grow vertically>?

Comment: Sorry yes I want to auto-resize when typing. I've updated the original post with this clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around I found a way to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8"/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.mx_internal;

            protected function changeTextArea():void
            {
                textArea.heightInLines = NaN;
            }

            protected function lineCount():void
            {
                label.text = textArea.textFlow.flowComposer.numLines.toString();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TextArea id="textArea"
                heightInLines="1"
                horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                change="changeTextArea()" focusOut="lineCount()"/>
    <s:Label id="label"/>
    <s:Button/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: That is correct answer. If you find it cumbersome to control "heightInLines" property within "change" event handler, you may want to add your comment at Adobe JIRA at corresponding closed bug " Spark TextArea heightInLines stopped working from SDK 4.0 to stable version 4.1" https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26781

Answer (score 0):

I just set the width/height to be a percentage of the container:

```
<s:TextArea width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Unless you are asking something else?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with flex hero, and as Bruno Trincão posted [here](http://www.eonflex.com/?p=398), `s:RichEditableText` works with `textArea.heightInLines = NaN;`